# OpenSSL libssl.so error undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_remove_padding'

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, libssl

I am currently patching a older version of OpenSSL to the latest stable 1.0.0o build (via import_openssl.sh)for use with a Android application via the NDK r10c.

While building the libssl.so sharedlibrary i am presented with the following errors.

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libssl.so
jni/openssl/ssl/s3_enc.c:542: error: undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_remove_padding'
jni/openssl/ssl/s3_enc.c:739: error: undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_record_digest_supported'
jni/openssl/ssl/s3_enc.c:764: error: undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_digest_record'
jni/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:464: error: undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_copy_mac'
jni/openssl/ssl/t1_enc.c:763: error: undefined reference to 'tls1_cbc_remove_padding'
jni/openssl/ssl/t1_enc.c:919: error: undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_record_digest_supported'
jni/openssl/ssl/t1_enc.c:925: error: undefined reference to 'ssl3_cbc_digest_record'
jni/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1058: error: undefined reference to 'dtls1_min_mtu'
```

Taking the first error for example, i can see a reference in the file s3_enc.c (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable/ssl/s3_enc.c)  to a function 'ssl3_cbc_remove_padding' but the actual function is nowhere to be seen, only a prototype in ssl_locl.h (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable/ssl/ssl_lib.c) so i am a little confused.

Any help or previous experience would be greatly appreciated in order to get these errors cleared. if you need me to elaborate further, please ask.

Comment: 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 are binary compatible. Why not just use the latest 1.0.1 and avoid the down-level feature issues and patching problem?

Comment: I am facing the same kind of problem when trying to build 0.9.8zc version. For some reason I had to use 0.9.8zc version. Is there any solution to this problem? Also note that If I create a standalone NDK project and build openssl, then everything is fine. But If I embed the same code in my actual project then this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the files `(s3_enc.c, t1_enc.c, ssl_lib.c)`, included in their respective `.mk` files or not. In my case it was not included so I just add these source files in `ssl/Android.mk` under `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` section.

Comment: Very similar to my final solution, my .mk files were missing files dependant for s3_enc.c, t1_enc.c and ssl_lib.c to compile (e.g. s3_cbc.c, d1_*.c etc). added them in manually and that seamed to do the trick.